# Using ls and cd comands on network folders

Tags: command-line, shared-folders, ls

Super-new linux/terminal user here-

Is it possible to use ls and cd comands directly on directories within a public folder on a NAS, or does the share need to me mounted within the root directory structure first?

If so, how would the path look?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This depend on how is the NAS set up?

Does it use windows sharing? Then you can use `smbclient` to connect to the server and there you can use `ls`and `cd`. Connect with something like `smbclient //192.168.2.10/Volume1` .

Does it use ftp? Then you can use `ftp` to connect to the server and use `cd` and `ls` again. Connect with something like: `ftp 192.168.2.10` .

Does it use sftp? Then you can use `sftp` to connect to the server and use `cd` and `ls` again. Connect with something like: `sftp user@192.168.2.10` .

And so on. So generally you don't need it to be mounted, because usually you can access the files with a client.

---

I expand the samba version, because you have that kind of share:

1. You need the ip of the NAS, e.g 192.168.2.10, then you type in a terminal:

   ```
   smbclient -L=192.168.2.10
   ```

   The server will ask for a password but because you said it is a public share you don't need one, just press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. Now you are presented with the shares services on the server, e.g.:

   ```
   Domain=[WORKGROUP] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 3.0.14a]

   Sharename       Type      Comment
   ---------       ----      -------
   Volume1         Disk      
   IPC$            IPC       IPC Service ()
   ADMIN$          IPC       IPC Service ()
   ```

   As you see I have only one Disk share named `Volume1`.
2. Now you type in

   ```
   smbclient //192.168.2.10/Volume1
   ```

   or

   ```
   smbclient \\\\192.168.2.10\\Volume1
   ```

   to access the `Volume1` share on the server with ip `192.168.2.10`. The server again asks for a password, just press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.
3. Now you are in the client and can browse the shared volume without mounting it to your file system.  You can type `help` to get the available commands, but if you are familiar with `ftp` than it is basically the same. You can use `ls` to list the directory contents, or `cd` to change directory. You can exit from the client with `quit`.

Using this way the share is not mounted to your file system, only the client communicates with the server. (I think this was your question.)

Comment: Thanks for the extra info. The NAS is set up as windows share using   samba.

Comment: @user234757 Then you can browse its contents with `smbclient` without mounting it.

Comment: oops - cut myself short on my first comment - it should have read: Thanks for the extra info. The NAS is set up as windows share using   samba. I have figured out how to mount share folders for that session using terminal, and mounting them automatically on log-on by amending the fstab file. (Using cifs rather than smb).
Is using the smbclient method above different to a temp mount? How would you apply the ls command - for instance showing the contents of the volume1 folder in your example?

Comment: @user234757 The difference is that this way nothing is mounted to the file system, just the client communicates with the server. I updated my answer.

Comment: I will give that a go. Thanks for time you have spent answering my question. Much appreciated.

Comment: I believe you should add `--user=username` at the end of the command. Atleast that's how it works for me to connect to SMB server which is present inside a virtual machine.

Answer (score 1):

Stumbled on this old thread and realized it is Wrong. Ubuntu 17.04, open up the file system explorer, navigate to the network directory, right-click, select "Open in Terminal". It works well.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely need to have the shares mounted onto the filesystem for any tool that work with it to see them.

You cannot `ls` a URI, nor `cd` into one.